# How to extract parameter types from a function type while omitting one parameter?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following interface which defines a function:

```
export declare interface NavigationGuard {
    (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext): NavigationGuardReturn | Promise<NavigationGuardReturn>;
}
```

I'd like to end up with this type:

```
export SomeNavigationGuardType = (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized): NavigationGuardReturn | Promise<NavigationGuardReturn>
```

Utilising the original `NavigationGuard` type ...

I have tried utilising the utility type `Parameters`, extracting and using `Omit` to remove the next param, but the `Parameters` utility type is extracting to a tuple.

I've tried utilising:

```
type NavigationGuardParams = Omit<Parameters<NavigationGuard>, 'next'>

export type UseRouterNivigationGuards = {
  beforeEach?: (arg: NavigationGuardParams) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
  beforeResolve?: (arg: NavigationGuardParams) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
  afterEach?: NavigationHookAfter
}
```

and

```
type NavigationGuardParams = Omit<Parameters<NavigationGuard>, 'next'>

export type UseRouterNivigationGuards = {
  beforeEach?: (...arg: NavigationGuardParams) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
  beforeResolve?: (...arg: NavigationGuardParams) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
  afterEach?: NavigationHookAfter
}
```

But both results in a usage / param error, the first giving this:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

The second attempt giving:

> Argument of type '[RouteLocationNormalized, RouteLocationNormalized]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationGuardParams'.

Is there a trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type with `infer` to remove the `next` element from the tuple returned by `Parameters`:

```
type SomeNavigationGuardType = (...args: Parameters<NavigationGuard> extends [...infer T, next: unknown] ? T : never) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
```

Comment: This works, but could you add that it needs to be used with my second attempt please ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply index the parameters from `Parameters`:

```
type SomeNavigationGuardType = (to: Parameters<NavigationGuard>[0], from: Parameters<NavigationGuard>[1]) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>
```

Comment: Appreciate this. But will "to" always be at index [0] and "from" always at index [1] ... ? I wanted to make this more generic. And what if upstream `NavigationGuard` adds another parameter alongside to, from and next. I basically want something very generic ...

Comment: "adds another parameter alongside to, from and next." would you still only want to omit `next`?

Comment: True, but I essentially do not at this moment in time want the user to be able to call next ... that is the job of the parent function that these functions will be called in.

Comment: Appreciate the answer though, so will up vote :)